# how to make an array of post id's in is_single

Tags: php, posts, array, single

For example, the code below only shows the page challenge for post id 2578. However i got 8 other posts that should have the same layout. All others should have the layout from challenge-2 etc. I was hoping i could do that by just adding commas between the ID's. like 2578, 2579, 2580 but that doesnt work. What do i need to do?

```
    if ( is_single( 2578 ) ) {
    get_template_part('partials/content', 'challenge');

    } 

    elseif ( is_single( ) )  {
    get_template_part('partials/challenge/content', 'challenge-2');
    get_template_part('partials/challenge/content', 'categories');
    get_template_part('partials/challenge/content', 'snake-checklist');
    get_template_part('partials/challenge/content', 'timeline'); 
    }
    ?>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set it the ids in a array like:

```
if ( is_single( array( '11717', '11723') ) ) {

}
```

Comment: Correct, except that post id's shouldn't be parsed as strings.

Comment: Both should work. Look: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/#user-contributed-notes
But your a right, it should not a string.

Comment: Yeah, mainly for programmer readability. In the end, the integer is converted to a string here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_single/